# Do _init pages work with MVC 4 the same way they do with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just curious, because I cannot seem to find any information explaining this.

Comment: I think you're using some terminology that is not in common use.  Define what you mean by an "_init page".  Do you things like Page_Init, Page_Load, etc?

Comment: My apologies, i was referring to "_init.cshtml" pages that would be purely code files and executed prior to any page being served within a folder. I just learned about this type of page and thought it would be a good place to stick role based authorization rules to protect access to certain parts of a site. But perhaps MVC typically does things like that elsewhere...probably within the controller correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The _init.cshtml pages (now renamed PageStart.cshtml in WebPages2) are not a feature of Razor, but rather a feature of the WebPages system.

WebPages do not have controllers or other mechanisms to separate view from code, so these were added as a way to help with that.

In any event, MVC does not use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean _underscore notation, no there is no such in MVC. 
There is also no page init event in MVC, here is comparison of MVC and WebForms lifecycles comparison.

Comment: That's only true when using Razor ViewEngine (or other non-WebForms ViewEngines).  If you're using the WebForms view engine, then it's possible to have a code-behind with Page_Init, Page_Load, etc... These are typically only used in legacy scenarios though and are not recommended.

Comment: Holly cow! But Controllers are decoupled from ViewEngines how is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I know it's mind boggling, but you can in fact have a code behind because the WebForms view engine does it's own processing when the view is rendered.  So basically Page_Load would happen when you return View() from the action method.

Comment: Please don't tell anybody about that, otherwise someday somebody can use it